# Converting String to Datetime2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to convert

```
@string='25/05/2016 09:00'
```

to `2016-05-25 09:00`.

`@string` is concatenation of `@string2='25/05/2016'` and `@string3='09:00'`

When I try to do this using

```
CONVERT(datetime, '25/05/2016 09:00')
```

I get the following error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, '25/05/2016 09:00', 103)
```

The [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) method takes 3 arguments: The first is the target data type, the second is the expression to convert, and the third is the style. In this case, 103 stands for British or French date format, which is `dd/mm/yyyy`.

```
Declare @string char(10)='25/05/2016'
Declare @string2 char(5)='09:00'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, @string + ' ' + @string2, 103)
```

Result: `2016-05-25 09:00:00.0000000` (`datetime2`)

Comment: Complete list of date format codes can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

thanks marc_s for putting my query in the right format.

I tried this and got the expected result, please advise if there is any other optimal way, thanks

```
 Declare @string varchar(20)='25/05/2016'
 Declare @string2 varchar(20)='09:00'
 Declare @string3 Varchar(20)=(SELECT Right(@string,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@string,4,2)+'-'+LEFT(@string,2)+' '+@string2)
 Select CONVERT(datetime,@string3) as _datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

add this statement before convert

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
```

so query look like this

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '25/05/2016 09:00')
```